# How do I destroy the zfcuser session variable manually within ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

Does anyone know how to destroy the Zfcuser session variable?

If certain events occur I would like to end the session?

I checked the wiki and the only discussion is about setting automatic timeout. I would like to  destroy the session manually.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going for a general logout function `session_destroy();` should suffice, otherwise just use `unset($_SESSION['zfcuser']);`